# document.getSelection().toString() is always " " in ie while working with iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to get the selected text onmouseup.

I also tried

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  var selectedData = contentWrapper.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selectedData)
}, 1008)
```

html code

```
<iframe src="url"></iframe>
```

js code

```js
var contentWrapper=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument;
contentWrapper.body.addEventListener('mouseup', this.CheckSelections, false);

function CheckSelections() {
  var selectedData = contentWrapper.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selectedData)
}
```

Comment: If the iframe uses a different domain than yours,  you'll face some Same Origin Policy issues.

Comment: yeah but in that case it should throw some error right like permission denied. But here I am able to get the content through contentWrapper.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.textContent but contentWrapper.getSelection().toString() is always showing as null string i.e ""

Comment: No IE to test, but can you confirm you can reproduce this issue with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be4sapwd/)? Also, does [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/be4sapwd/1/) change anything?

Comment: getSelection() is a function, you don't check what it returns before using the result, always check a functions return value.

Answer (score 0):

This way it works in IE, Chrome & FF (testing on local), but I am not able to touch iframe here.

```js
function showSelection() {
  var selectedData = document.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selectedData)
}

var contentWrapper;
function attachIF() {
  if(location.href == "https://stacksnippets.net/js") return;
  var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifr.src="javascript:'"+ // Access is denied. Here on stackoverflow.com
    "<script>window.onload=function(){"+
      "document.write(\\'<script>if(document.domain)document.domain=\\\""+document.domain+"\\\";"+
      "document.write(\""+parent.document.body.innerText+"\");"+
      "<\\\\/script>\\');"+
      "document.close();"+
      "parent.contentWrapper = document;"+
      "document.body.onmouseup=parent.CheckSelections;"+
      "};<\/script>'";
  document.body.appendChild(ifr);
}

function CheckSelections() {
  var selectedData = contentWrapper.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selectedData)
}
```

```html
<body onmouseup="showSelection()" onload=attachIF()>
  <iframe src="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></iframe>
  Some text to be selected.
</body>
```